# Oracle mapviewer - problem with caching

Tags: oracle, plsql, maps

I need help with clearing geometry cache. In my web application there is a need to clear cache after changing the geometry data in database. I'm using maps with tile layers and for them i want cache to be cleared using triggers in databae. I've tried with passing request to the servlet **mcsadmin** (using utl_http in pl/sql) with xml(map_cache_admin_request ) post parameter but it doesnt work because of not being logged in to this admin servlet. Could anyone help me to find a solution?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm using Oracle Mapviewer 11R1

Comment: the problem is with in-memory cache. how to clear it automatically after changes in geomtry data?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a one year old question but if someone finds, it might prove helpful
all you need to do is clear the cache from the mapviewer admin panel and ...unfortunately restart the server (either its oc4j or weblogic)